# API function to add an Action to an Event or Schedule?

Tags: anylogic

I need to add an Action to a Schedule object that is being created through the API. There are documented interfaces to set almost all the options except the Action. How are Actions attached to these Objects?

When I attempt to programmatically add a new event, read from a separate configuration file, to a Schedule object I get errors stating that the Schedule has already been initialized and that I must construct a new object and add its configuration manually. I can do most of that using the available Schedule API. I can set up everything about the Schedule except the Action code.

The Schedule is used in a Process Model. Looking at the model in the Java editor, I see the code I'm trying to replicate via the API in a function that looks like this:

```
  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public void executeActionOf( EventTimeout _e ) {
    if ( _e == _fuelDeliverySchedule_Action_xjal ) {
      Schedule<Integer> self = this.fuelDeliverySchedule;
      Integer value = fuelDeliverySchedule.getValue();

logger.info("{} received {} pounds of fuel", this.getName(), this.fuelDeliverySchedule.getValue());

this.fuelAvailablePounds += fuelDeliverySchedule.getValue();

;
      _fuelDeliverySchedule_Action_xjal.restartTo( fuelDeliverySchedule.getTimeOfNextValue() );
      return;
    }
    super.executeActionOf( _e );
  }
```

Maybe I can use something like this to create my own action function, but I'm not sure how to make the Scheduled event use it.

Thanks,
Thom

Answer (score 2):

[**Edited (expanded/rewrote) 03.11.2014 after more user detail on the context.**]

You clarified the context with

> When I attempt to programatically add "a thing that happens", read
>   from a separate configuration file, to a Schedule object I get errors
>   stating that the Schedule has already been initialized and that I must
>   construct a new object and add its configuration manually. I can do
>   most of that using the available Schedule API. I can set up everything
>   about the Schedule except the Action code.

(You might want to edit that into the question... In general, it's always good to explain the context for why you're trying to do the thing.)

I think I understand now. I presume that your config file contains scheduling details and, when you say you were trying to "add a thing that happens" (which errored), you meant that you were trying to change the scheduling 'pattern' in the `Schedule`. So your problem is that, since you couldn't adjust a pre-existing schedule, you had to instantiate (create) your own programmatically, but the `Schedule` API doesn't allow you to set the action code (as seen on the GUI schedule element).

This is a fairly involved solution so bear with me. I give a brief 'tl;dr'
summary before diving into the detail.

### Summary

You can't programmatically code an AnyLogic action (for *any* element) because that would amount to
dynamically creating a Java class. Solving your problem requires recognising
that the schedule *GUI* element creates both a `Schedule` instance *and* a
timeout event (`EventTimeout`) instance to trigger the action. You can therefore create these two elements explicitly yourself (the former dynamically). The trick is to reset the timeout event when you replace the `Schedule` instance (to trigger at the next 'flip' point of the new `Schedule`).

[**Actually, from your wording, I suspect that the action is always the same but, for generality, I show how you could handle it if your config file details might want to change the nature of the action as well as those of the scheduling pattern.**]

### Detail

The issue is that the GUI element (confusingly) *isn't* just a `Schedule` instance
in terms of the code it generates. There is one (with the same name as that of
the GUI element), which just contains the schedule 'pattern' and, as in the API,
has methods to determine when the next on/off period (for an on/off schedule) occurs. (So
it is kind of fancy calendar functionality.) But AnyLogic also generates a
*timeout event* to actually perform the action; if you look further in the code
generated, you'll see stuff similar to the below (assuming your GUI schedule is called
`fuelSchedule`, with Java comments added by
me):

```
  // Definition of the timeout event
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public EventTimeout _fuelSchedule_Action_xjal = new EventTimeout(this);

  // First occurrence time of the event as the next schedule on/off change
  // time
  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public double getFirstOccurrenceTime( EventTimeout _e ) {

    if ( _e == _fuelSchedule_Action_xjal ) return fuelSchedule.getTimeOfValue() == time() ? time() : fuelSchedule.getTimeOfNextValue();
    return super.getFirstOccurrenceTime( _e );
  }

  // After your user action code, the event is rescheduled for the next
  // schedule on/off change time
   _fuelSchedule_Action_xjal.restartTo( fuelSchedule.getTimeOfNextValue() );
```

i.e., this creates an event which triggers each time the schedule 'flips', and performs the action specified in the GUI schedule element.

So there is no action to change on the `Schedule` instance; it's actually related to the `EventTimeout` instance. However, you can't programmatically change it there (or create a new one dynamically) for the same reason that you can't change the action of *any* AnyLogic element:
this would effectively be programmatically
creating a Java class definition, which isn't possible without very specialised
Java code. (You can create Java source code in a string and
dynamically run a Java compiler on it to generate a class. However, this is very
'advanced' Java, has lots of potential pitfalls, and I would definitely not
recommend going that route. You would also have to be creating source for a user subclass
of `EventTimeout`, since you don't know the correct source code for AnyLogic's proprietary `EventTimeout` class, and this might change per release in any case.)

But you shouldn't need to: there should be a strict set of possible actions that your config file can contain. (They *can't* be arbitrary Java code snippets, since they have to 'fit in' with the simulation.) So you can do what you want by programmatically creating the `Schedule` *but with a GUI-created timeout event that you adjust accordingly*(assuming an off/on schedule here and that there is
only one schedule active at once; obviously tweak this skeleton to your needs
and I haven't completely tested this in AnyLogic):

**1.** Have an AnyLogic variable `activeAction` which specifies the current active
action. (I take this as an `int` here for simplicity, but it's better to use a
Java `enum` which is the same as an AnyLogic 7 Option List, and can just be
created in raw Java in AnyLogic 6.)

**2.** Create a **variable** in the GUI, say called `fuelSchedule`, of type `Schedule` but with initial value `null`. Create a separate timeout event, say called `fuelScheduleTrigger`, in User Control mode, with action as:

```
// Perform the appropriate action (dependent on activeAction)
doAppropriateScheduleAction();
// Set the event to retrigger at the next schedule on/off switch time
fuelScheduleTrigger.restartTo(fuelSchedule.getTimeOfNextValue());
```

(Being in User Control mode, this event isn't yet triggered to initially fire, which is what we want.)

**3.** Code a set of functions for each of the different action alternatives; let's say
there are only 2 (`fuelAction1` and `fuelAction2`) here as an example. Code
`doAppropriateScheduleAction` as:

```
if (activeAction == 1) {
    fuelAction1();
}
else if (activeAction == 2) {
    fuelAction2();
}
```

**4.** In your code which reads the config file and gets updated schedule info.
(presumably run from a cyclic timeout event or similar), have this *replace*
`fuelSchedule` with a new instance with the revised schedule pattern (as you've
been doing), set `activeAction` appropriately, and then *reset* the timeout event to
the new `fuelSchedule.getTimeOfValue()` time:

```
[set up fuelSchedule and activeAction]
// Reset schedule action to match revised schedule
fuelScheduleTrigger.restartTo(fuelSchedule.getTimeOfNextValue());
```

I think this works OK in the edge case when the new `Schedule` had its next 'flip' at the time
you set it up. (If you restart an event to the current time, I think it schedules an event OK at the current time which will occur next if there are no other events also scheduled for the current time; actually, it will definitely occur next if you are using a LIFO simultaneous-time-scheduling regime---see [my blog post](http://ofscienceandsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/subtleties-of-anylogic-event-scheduling.html).)

### Alternative & AnyLogic Enhancement

An alternative is to create a 'full' schedule in the GUI with action as earlier. Your config file reading code can replace the underlying `Schedule` instance and then reset the *internal* AnyLogic-generated timeout event. However, this is less preferable because you are relying on an internally-named AnyLogic event (which might also change in future AnyLogic releases, breaking your code).

AnyLogic could help this situation by adding a method to the `Schedule` API that gets the related timeout event; e.g., `getActionTriggeringEventTimeout()`. Then you *would* be able to 'properly' restart it *and* the `Schedule` API would make much clearer that the `Schedule` was always associated with an `EventTimeout` that did the triggering for the action.

Of course, AnyLogic could also go further by changing Schedule to allow scheduling details to be changed dynamically (and internally handling the required updates to the timeout event if it continued to be designed like that), but that's a lot more work and there may be deeper technical reasons why they wanted the schedule pattern to be fixed once the Schedule is initialised.

Any AnyLogic support staff reading?

Comment: When I attempt to programatically add "a thing that happens", read from a separate configuration file, to a Schedule object I get errors stating that the Schedule has already been initialized and that I must construct a new object and add its configuration manually. I can do most of that using the available Schedule API. I can set up everything about the Schedule except the Action code.